# Pick a value from a set based on combination of values from two other sets in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations

I have two columns in Excel with values like: **High**, **Medium** and **Low**. In third column, I need to put a value from another set (A,B,C,D), based on the following logic:

[image]

So for example:

```
Column1 Column2  Column3
High    High     A
Medium  High     A
Medium  Medium   B
Low     Medium   C
```

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(FILTER($B$2:$D$4,$A$2:$A$4=A9),$B$1:$D$1=B9)
```

Or `XLOOKUP()`

```
=XLOOKUP(B9,$B$1:$D$1,XLOOKUP(A9,$A$2:$A$4,$B$2:$D$4))
```

For all versions of Excel, try-

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH(A9,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(B9,$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative to accomplish the combinations using <kbd>HSTACK( )</kbd> & <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E1</kbd>

```
=HSTACK(
 TOCOL(IFS(B2:D4<>"",A2:A4)),
 TOCOL(IFS(B2:D4<>"",B1:D1)),
 TOCOL(B2:D4))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative this could also be done without lookups, spilling the combinations and it's value:
`=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(TOCOL("|"&A2:A4&"|"&B1:D1&"|"&B2:D4),"|",SEQUENCE(,3)),"|")`

[image]

Or if you don't have a start range:

```
=LET(a,{"High","Medium","Low"},
     b,{"A","B","C","D"},
     s,SEQUENCE(,3),
TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(TOCOL("|"&TOCOL(a)&"|"&a&"|"&INDEX(b,s+TOCOL(s)-2)),"|",s),"|"))
```